# Prettier error `␍⏎····mapStateToProps,␍⏎····mapDispatchToProps,␍⏎··` with `mapStateToProps,·mapDispatchToProps`

Tags: reactjs, eslint, prettier, eslintrc

I encountered the following error message
`` Replace `␍⏎····mapStateToProps,␍⏎····mapDispatchToProps,␍⏎··` with `mapStateToProps,·mapDispatchToProps`  prettier/prettier ``

The guys who work in my team don't have that error in their editors. Itried disabling my eslint and prettier plugins in VSCode and also uninstalled prettier globally but had no luck. I also tried to remove the `prettierrc.js` and

Here is my `prettierrc.js` and `eslintrc.js` files. But the error persisted anyway

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
module.exports = {
    printWidth: 80,
    tabWidth: 2,
    useTabs: false,
    semi: true,
    singleQuote: true,
    trailingComma: 'all',
    endOfLine: 'auto',
};
```

And `eslintrc.js`

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  extends: [
    'airbnb',
    'plugin:import/errors',
    'plugin:import/warnings',
    'prettier',
    'prettier/react',
  ],
  plugins: ['flowtype', 'prettier', 'import'],
  parser: 'babel-eslint',
  rules: {
    'linebreak-style': 0,
    'prefer-const': 0,
    'spaced-comment': 0,
    'padded-blocks': 0,
    'import/imports-first': 0,
    'import/prefer-default-export': 0,
    'import/no-extraneous-dependencies': 0,
    'comma-dangle': 0,
    'no-shadow': 0,
    'arrow-body-style': 0,
    'quote-props': 0,
    'no-unused-vars': 1,
    'consistent-return': 0,
    'max-len': 0,
    'no-use-before-define': ['error', { functions: false, classes: true }],
    'no-underscore-dangle': 'off',
    'react/prefer-stateless-function': ['off'],
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': ['off'],
    'react/forbid-prop-types': ['off'],
    'editor.formatOnSave': true,
    // Enable per-language
    '[javascript]': {
      'editor.formatOnSave': true,
    },
    'react/no-danger': 0,
    'react/prop-types': 0,
    'no-throw-literal': 'error',
    'no-bitwise': ['off'],
    'dot-notation': ['off'],
    'prettier/prettier': ['error'],
    'flowtype/define-flow-type': 1,
    camelcase: ['off'],
    'jsx-a11y/label-has-for': ['off'],
    'no-nested-ternary': 'off',
    'react/no-this-in-sfc': 'off',
    'no-param-reassign': 'off',
    'react/sort-comp': [
      1,
      {
        order: [
          'static-methods',
          'instance-variables',
          'lifecycle',
          '/^on.+$/',
          'everything-else',
          'rendering',
        ],
        groups: {
          rendering: ['/^render.+$/', 'render'],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 6,
    sourceType: 'module',
    ecmaFeatures: {
      spread: true,
      legacyDecorators: true,
    },
  },
  globals: {
    global: true,
    document: true,
    window: true,
  },
  settings: {
    'import/extensions': ['.js', '.jsx'],
    'import/parser': 'babel-eslint',
    'import/resolver': {
      // You can use only webpack but with this approach webstorm doesn't show
      // any red highlight for alias imports
      // If you forget to add alias here build still will work if there are aliases in
      // webpack.config but with this webstorm works better.
      // eslint-import-resolver-alias
      alias: [
        ['app', path.join(__dirname, 'src/app/')],
        ['assets', path.join(__dirname, 'src/assets/')],
        // ['TT', 'src/app/test/'],
      ],
      // It also works but with alias there are no red highlight in webstorm
      // and with this approach build works but I still see red highlights in webstorm
      // eslint-import-resolver-webpack
      webpack: {
        config: './webpack/webpack.prod.js',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Do check you `vscode` settings to ensure `prettier.endOfLine` is not set to anything but `auto`.
2. Do check that `.editorconfig` (if any) does not conflict with your `.prettierrc` configuration.